# How do i stop htaccess redirecting loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

i am trying to redirect `/article/1` to `/article/1/title-of-blog`
using this htaccess line

> Redirect 301 /article/1 /article/1/title-of-blog

when i do that
my new link will be

https://www.mysite,com/article/1/title-of-blog/title-of-blog/title-of-blog/title-of-blog

as this loop keep going

so how to fix this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Is `/article/1` the end of the URL you want to redirect? If so, use `$` to indicate that this is where the URL ends. ie. `RewriteRule /article/1$ https://example.com/article/1/title-of-blog [R=301]`

Comment: @Rounin Still not working , actually no redirecting happens at all
and yes '/article/1' is the end of the url

Comment: it work , i was had to clean the caches , thanks alot @Rounin

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you, @shehabmustafaaa. I have added my comment above as an answer below. You can upvote it and accept it as the correct answer, if you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `/article/1` the end of the URL you want to redirect?

If so, use `$` to indicate that this is where the URL ends.

**ie.** `RewriteRule /article/1$ https://example.com/article/1/title-of-blog [R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, the destination should be a full URL. This will look something like:

```
Redirect 301 /article/1 http://yourdomain/article/1/title-of-blog
```

For example, if your domain was example.com, you would have:

```
Redirect 301 /article/1 http://example.com/article/1/title-of-blog
```